# Quick \ automatic switching of 'from' account in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I added my business email account to Gmail. however, I find the standard method of changing the 'from' account (the pull down menu for each mail) to be tedious and error prone.

I'm looking for a method (or a plugin \ extension \ ...)
That will allow one of:

1. automatically select the from address based on the recipients
2. change the default from address in one click (that is - all mails composed in this session will use the same account - until switching back)

Comment: Not sure it's an answer to your problem, but in Settings>Accounts and Import I have the option "when replying to a message" and it has "reply from the same address the message was sent to" - which cuts down significantly the number of times I need to change the from message.

Comment: You might also consider creating a greasemonkey script

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the Settings> Accounts and Imports and set the settings as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]